# Definite integration technique

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution

What's wrong with this solution of the
$$ \int_0^1 15 \sqrt{9-5x} \, dx \enspace ?$$
$$= \enspace 15\int_0^1 \sqrt{9-5x} \, dx $$
$$ u=9-5x $$
$$ du = -5dx $$
$$ \frac{-15}{5} \int_0^1 \sqrt{u} \, du $$
$$ -3 \int_0^1 \sqrt{u} \, du $$
Which will later lead to the integral of $80$. Other answers say it is $38$. What technique did the use?

Comment: If you want to use u-substitution, don't forget to switch the integral bounds.

Comment: $\int_0^1 15 \sqrt{9-5x} \, dx \le \int_0^1 15 \sqrt{9} \, dx=45<80$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bounds on $u$ are wrong. $u=9-5x$ ranges from $9-5\cdot0$ to $9-5\cdot1$ since $x$ ranges from $0$ to $1$.